# Rails: storing arrays in DB vs. setting up relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Setting:** There are two models with the following attributes.

1. Person: name, age, work_experience, available_dates
2. WorkExperience: job_title, starting_date, ending_date

Then, I can do the following

```
Person
  has_many work_experiences

WorkExperience
  belongs_to Person
```

**Q1:** Should `available_dates` be an attribute (`array of dates`) or a child (e.g. `Person has_many available_dates`)?

**Q2:** Can `Person` have `work_experiences` field that's just an array of objects instead of an individual table in DB?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: As in all design questions, I think the answer is "it depends."

On Q1:

I've done both ways before. If I were making this decision, I would consider the following:

- Do I see myself adding more information to available_dates in a very near future? For example, it could be location, timezone, commute distance, and so on that would make this data into "availability" in general. In that
  case, I'd rather create separate objects with association.
- Do I see myself reusing these dates in some other place in my code? Then I'd rather make them into separate objects and persist.

On Q2:

I don't think it'd be good for your sanity. DB has simple datatypes and are not designed to retain object models.

Answer (score 0):

On Q1 I would go with an association instead of an array as it provides more flexibility. So a child, as you call it is what I would do.

On Q2 I would also go with a separate WorkExperience Model as it also provides more flexibility and room for growth. Also the array might get a bit messy as a Person starts gathering work experiences and querying for information might get more complicated than it needs to be with an array. With a separate model Active Record will give you a lot of tools you can use to dig into a person's work experiences.

Hope that helps.